# How to use the second parameter of lastIndexOf() method in Javascript string object?

Tags: javascript

```
"This apple is my apple".lastIndexOf("apple"); // returns value of 17
"This apple is my apple".lastIndexOf("apple",12); // returns value of 5
"This apple is my apple".lastIndexOf("apple", 3); // returns value of -1, not found
```

Hi guys!

I understand the first two examples, but why the third doesn't return 5?

Like `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` also takes an optional second parameter, which is an index value of where to start the search, counted from the right, so the string 'apple' should match the position 5. But I still got the result of -1?

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for the `lastIndexOf` is:

```
string.lastIndexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

where `fromIndex` is optional and represents the index from which to start looking. However, the search is performed **backwards**, so starting from position 3 in your example would be searching through string `"This"`;

Comment: In the last example it would search through the string "This"; the second argument specifies the starting position from which to search backwards.

Answer (score 3):

The search is done backwards.  So if the "start" is 3, it will start at the forth character and work backwards.  That means it will only search from the `s` in "This" and work backwards, which does not contain "apple".

Comment: That what I thought, but `'This apple is my apple'.lastIndexOf('apple', 5)` return `5`.

Comment: Right, because it starts with the 6th character (it's 0 indexed).  The 6th character is "a" which is a match because it's the first character in "apple".

Comment: @ZenMaster It doesn't *truncate* the string; you're starting at the 'a', and that's part of 'apple'.

Comment: @DaveNewton that doesn't make sense. 5 means that I am searching starting from `'a'` **backwards**, isn't it? Essentially searching `'This a'` string?

Comment: Those are the characters it searches in that it checks to see if that word exists at any of those positions.  It DOES exist at position 5.  It's not exactly intuitive, but it is how it works.

Comment: @ZenMaster And starting from "a", moving backwards, where's the last occurence of "apple" begin? At the "a". The entire string is still there; everything past the "a" still exists, and it's where the word apple starts.

Comment: @Dave Newton Aha... I wish he'd un-accept my answer - which is technically correct, but apparently not quite understood by myself.

Comment: @ZenMaster Well, you understood the third example, which is what the question was about ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is '5'. 
Then the count will start from left to right i.e., from word 'heck'. Now it will count back from letter "h" to white space and the letter "t" and to "a", "h" and to "w". Hope it makes a scene. If you put '4' in place of '5', it'll output '-1' because then it will count from white space and to letter "t" and to "a" and after that there's no word "heck" exists.

```
var st = 'What heck the heck', 
index = st.lastIndexOf('heck', 5); 
//It goes backward from the number you assigned it
```